# get subnet mask and useable IP addresses

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

im fairly new to this whole area inc the area of binary etc.
Can someone provide me with a detailed answer to the below as I am unable to locate one online

Given the IP address 192.168.1.0 and the subnet mask 255.255.255.0, you have been asked to create an IP addressing scheme where each subnet has a minimum of 18 IP addresses. Answer the following:

1. What is the new subnet mask?
2. How many subnets are created?
3. How many useable IP addresses are available per subnet?
4. Assuming the use of subnet zero what is the range of useable IP addresses for the 3rd subnet?

Comment: Should we really do your homework?

Comment: Sorry, This was in no way a way of getting the answers as we have nine others to do. I was just seriously stuck and needed a way to discover how to work out the answers

Answer (score 3):

There's a tool on Linux / Unix called ipcalc

This shows that

```
ipcalc 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 0.0.0.31

WILDCARD
Address:   192.168.1.0          11000000.10101000.00000001. 00000000
Netmask:   255.255.255.0 = 24   11111111.11111111.11111111. 00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.255            00000000.00000000.00000000. 11111111
=>
Network:   192.168.1.0/24       11000000.10101000.00000001. 00000000
HostMin:   192.168.1.1          11000000.10101000.00000001. 00000001
HostMax:   192.168.1.254        11000000.10101000.00000001. 11111110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.255        11000000.10101000.00000001. 11111111
Hosts/Net: 254                   Class C, Private Internet

Subnets after transition from /24 to /27

Netmask:   255.255.255.224 = 27 11111111.11111111.11111111.111 00000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.31             00000000.00000000.00000000.000 11111

 1.
Network:   192.168.1.0/27       11000000.10101000.00000001.000 00000
HostMin:   192.168.1.1          11000000.10101000.00000001.000 00001
HostMax:   192.168.1.30         11000000.10101000.00000001.000 11110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.31         11000000.10101000.00000001.000 11111
Hosts/Net: 30                    Class C, Private Internet

 2.
Network:   192.168.1.32/27      11000000.10101000.00000001.001 00000
HostMin:   192.168.1.33         11000000.10101000.00000001.001 00001
HostMax:   192.168.1.62         11000000.10101000.00000001.001 11110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.63         11000000.10101000.00000001.001 11111
Hosts/Net: 30                    Class C, Private Internet

 3.
Network:   192.168.1.64/27      11000000.10101000.00000001.010 00000
HostMin:   192.168.1.65         11000000.10101000.00000001.010 00001
HostMax:   192.168.1.94         11000000.10101000.00000001.010 11110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.95         11000000.10101000.00000001.010 11111
Hosts/Net: 30                    Class C, Private Internet

 4.
Network:   192.168.1.96/27      11000000.10101000.00000001.011 00000
HostMin:   192.168.1.97         11000000.10101000.00000001.011 00001
HostMax:   192.168.1.126        11000000.10101000.00000001.011 11110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.127        11000000.10101000.00000001.011 11111
Hosts/Net: 30                    Class C, Private Internet

 5.
Network:   192.168.1.128/27     11000000.10101000.00000001.100 00000
HostMin:   192.168.1.129        11000000.10101000.00000001.100 00001
HostMax:   192.168.1.158        11000000.10101000.00000001.100 11110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.159        11000000.10101000.00000001.100 11111
Hosts/Net: 30                    Class C, Private Internet

 6.
Network:   192.168.1.160/27     11000000.10101000.00000001.101 00000
HostMin:   192.168.1.161        11000000.10101000.00000001.101 00001
HostMax:   192.168.1.190        11000000.10101000.00000001.101 11110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.191        11000000.10101000.00000001.101 11111
Hosts/Net: 30                    Class C, Private Internet

 7.
Network:   192.168.1.192/27     11000000.10101000.00000001.110 00000
HostMin:   192.168.1.193        11000000.10101000.00000001.110 00001
HostMax:   192.168.1.222        11000000.10101000.00000001.110 11110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.223        11000000.10101000.00000001.110 11111
Hosts/Net: 30                    Class C, Private Internet

 8.
Network:   192.168.1.224/27     11000000.10101000.00000001.111 00000
HostMin:   192.168.1.225        11000000.10101000.00000001.111 00001
HostMax:   192.168.1.254        11000000.10101000.00000001.111 11110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.255        11000000.10101000.00000001.111 11111
Hosts/Net: 30                    Class C, Private Internet


Subnets:   8
Hosts:     240
```

So the answer to your questions are

1. 255.255.255.224
2. 8
3. 30
4. 192.168.1.65 to 192.168.1.94